# Why does rabbitmq server stop without a clear reason?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord

Operating system is redhat.
I run the command "./rabbitmq-server &" to start rabbitmq as a daemon and it works fine.

After approximately 2 hours:
The command "./rabbitmqctl status" gives node down

I check the logs but there doesn't seem to be a crash reason:

rabbitmq/log/rabbit@prod.log:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 5-Jun-2018::21:15:05 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1567.0> (10.11.250.20:60033 -> 10.11.250.20:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Jun-2018::21:15:05 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1576.0> (10.11.250.20:60038 -> 10.11.250.20:5672)
"That's when I notice that node is down and I start the server again "
=INFO REPORT==== 6-Jun-2018::04:39:28 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.2.3 on Erlang R16B03-1
Copyright (C) 2007-2013 GoPivotal, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Jun-2018::04:39:28 ===
node           : rabbit@prod
home dir       : /home
config file(s) : (none)
cookie hash    : drMb4wUv2N33/CO4rvIpdg==
log            : rabbitmq/log/rabbit@prod.log
sasl log       : rabbitmq/log/rabbit@prod-sasl.log
database dir   : rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@prod
```

rabbitmq/log/rabbit@prod-sasl.log:

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 5-Jun-2018::18:24:59 ===
     Supervisor: {<0.1367.0>,rabbit_channel_sup_sup}
     Context:    shutdown_error
     Reason:     shutdown
     Offender:   [{nb_children,1},
                  {name,channel_sup},
                  {mfargs,{rabbit_channel_sup,start_link,[]}},
                  {restart_type,temporary},
                  {shutdown,infinity},
                  {child_type,supervisor}]
```

I need some ideas what of what could be the reason as I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ `3.2.3` is an ancient version that is no longer supported. You should be using the latest version with Erlang 19.3 or later. Please find installation instructions [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html).

Finally, you should be starting RabbitMQ via your init scripts or `systemd`, not via the `rabbitmq-server` command. Please see [this section](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html#running-rpm).